# How to use different default props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a react component that receives an id from its props.

```js
export type MyComponentProps = {
  id: string
}

export const MyComponent = function(props: MyComponentProps) {
  return (
    <div>{props.id}</div>
  );
}
```

Now, I want to make the id optional, but I do have a requirement to use identifiers so I make the id as optional and add a default prop.

```js
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

export type MyComponentProps = {
  id?: string
}

export const MyComponent = function(props: MyComponentProps) {
  return (
    <div>{props.id}</div>
  );
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  id: `MyComponent-${v4()}`
}
```

Done! Except, now, if I render 2 different instances of *MyComponent* they will have the same id. How do I work around this? What I did is the following, but I am no react expert and I don't know if there is another way to accomplish this.

```js
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

export type MyComponentProps = {
  id?: string
}

export const MyComponent = function(props: MyComponentProps) {
  const id = props.id?? `MyComponent-${v4()}`;
  return (
    <div>{id}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: One problem with your final implementation, potentially, is that the ID changes every time the component renders. But it's unclear what you actually need the ID for, maybe that's OK.

Comment: The id is used for the html component attributes required by bootstrap to... say open an accordion for example. So, due to the nature of UUIDs it won't really make a difference recalculating the ID every time (as long as they are unique), from a performance perspective, and at a larger scale it may cause some impact. So using a state to store that id as stated by @Ben West in the answer below is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a per-component ID that stays the same between renders, you'll need to put it in state.

```
export const MyComponent = function(props: MyComponentProps) {
  const [defaultId] = useState(v4)
  const id = props.id ?? defaultId
  return (
    <div>{id}</div>
  );
}
```